# In Vim is there more than one way to leave insert mode?

Tags: vim

There are several commands that do something and then enter insert mode. Are there also commands that leave insert mode and do things?

For example, I frequently do this...

<kbd>control</kbd><kbd>[</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>return</kbd>

Before I create a mapping, is there already Vim command that does that?

Comment: If I'm reading you correctly, you want to leave insert mode and save the file?  Is that a correct?

Comment: Yes. But "yes" is only three characters. There. Now I have more than 15.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there isn't a native command in vim to save a file like that, but you can certainly do it with the imap I dropped in.  Personally, I try not to use insert mode mappings.  I like the separation of modes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you'd like to map a few keys to do things like save a file while in insert mode, you can use the [`imap` command](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:imap).  This binds <kbd>F2</kbd> to exit insert mode and save the file:

```
:imap <F2> <Esc>:w<CR>
```

This binds <kbd>F2</kbd> to exit insert mode, save the file, and re-enter insert mode:

```
:imap <F2> <Esc>:w<CR>a
```

Or:

```
:imap <F2> <C-o>:w<CR>
```

Comment: My mapping for save is Ctrl+S: 
`noremap <C-S> :update<CR>`  
`vnoremap <C-S> <C-C>:update<CR>`  
`inoremap <C-S> <ESC>:update<CR>`  and on the mac I bind iTerm2's Cmd+S to Ctrl+S. This takes it out of insert mode if I was in insert mode

Answer (score 27):

In addition to Esc (which is identical to ^[), ^C also exits insert mode.

Comment: I really don't remember where I found that one but ALT+0 will also exit the insertion mode, i find that shortcut very easy to press

Comment: @vdegenne: That's because Alt+0 (on your terminal) sends the two characters `Esc`, then `0`. The `Esc` exits insert mode, and then the `0` moves to the start of the line, just like pressing those two keys separately.

Answer (score 18):

The only one I can think of is `c-o`, which lets you run one command in normal mode then drops you back into insert mode.

For example, `a<c-o>~b` would result in `Ab`.

Comment: But it doesn't do things, does it?

Comment: No, you're right – it only lets you do stuff, it doesn't "do things for you", so to speak.

Comment: For the record:
imap <Leader>w <C-o>:w<CR>
"does do things". Choose an appropriate key combination for the map and there you go.

Comment: Ah, yes, I hadn't thought thought about mentioning imap because I thought the poster was asking about "stock" commands. Very good point.

Answer (score 3):

ALt + the command lets you execute a command from INSERT mode, for example [reference](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Avoid_the_escape_key):

alt+o to open newline

alt+A to append

Answer (score 2):

Pressing Ctrl-L leaves insert mode in evim, so why not in regular vim, too?  Add this to your vimrc:
  :imap

Or if you don't want to configure vim use Ctrl-[, as suggested by others.

Comment: Thanks, I copy/pasted a string of commands in a terminal which had already "vim " written and I was stuck in a non-exitable INSERT mode vim. Ctrl+L solved it.